# Javascript issue with check all checkboxes on load

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a button that when clicked will select / deselect all checkoxes that are output on the page. This works great. I want them to load deselected and when the button is clicked they go selected. Right now I can only get it to work by having them load selected. I have tried messing around with this code but I cannot get these to load deselected. I'm not great with javascript. Can anyone see how I would do that with this code? Or do I have to do it a different way?

```
var checkflag = "true";
function check(field) {
  if (checkflag == "false") {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
      field[i].checked = true;
    }
    checkflag = "true";
    return "Deselect All";
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
      field[i].checked = false;
    }
    checkflag = "false";
    return "Select All";
  }
}

<input class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block" type="button" name="CheckAll" value="Deselect All" onClick="this.value=check(this.form,true)"     style="width:115px;">
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for the checkboxes?

Comment: JavaScript has `true` and `false` boolean constants. You need not use strings.

Comment: Maybe just the `checkflag` variable needs to be initialized with the opposite value …?

Comment: `onClick="this.value=check(this.form,true)"` here you have 2 arguments, but function `check` has only 1 argument - `function check(field)`.

Comment: I have tried to initialize the variable as "false" that did not do anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should put you on the right track.  You would just need to modify the 'document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')' line.  Make sure you select the boxes in your document.  All [nodelists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) have access to the forEach method. The ternary operator simply checks to see if the the .checked value is true.  If so it will set it to false.  Else it will set it to true.

```
<body>
  <button name="checkAll">Un/Check All</button>
</body>
<script>

const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
const checkAll = document.querySelector('checkAll');

function toggleAll(field) {
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => 
    checkbox.checked ? checkbox.checked = false : checkbox.checked = true);
};

checkAll.addEventListener('click', toggleAll);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I played around with this method and got it working. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the form, in the function call. Inside the check()-Function you need to get the fields from the form.

like:

```
check( form, newStat ) {
  var fields = form.fields;
  for (field in fields ) {
    field.checked = newStat;
  }
}
```

This is by no means tested code. Just take this as "pseudo code"